# Squashing a 3D matrix into an array of vectors with indices in vector

Tags: python, numpy

So I have a numpy array of size (w, h, d) where w is the image width, h is the image height, d is the dimension of it.

My goal is to turn this into a list of vectors for all of the pixels (so list of w*h size) and have it be such that the indices are packed along with the pixel.

So essentially [[i,j,r,g,b],[i,j,r,g,b],...] where ij is the coordinates of the pixel. I have done this using a loop but I am trying to do this without a loop in a numpy efficient way.

Comment: I’m curious, why the change in format?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:
Given some example input: `a=np.random.randint(4,size=(5,4,3))`,

you can first reshape it into 2D array of size `(wh,d)`:

```
b=a.reshape((a.shape[0]*a.shape[1],a.shape[2]))
```

Next, you can use list comprehensions, marching through the array `b`:

```
 [np.concatenate(([i%a.shape[0],int(i/a.shape[0])],c)) for i,c in enumerate(b)]
```

Comment: Are you sure it shouldn't be a.shape[1]?

Comment: @J.Doe, maybe, this is a sketch.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way using only numpy functions and no loops.

```
a = np.random.randint(4,size=(5,4,3))

# be careful with a.shape[1] coming first
x, y = np.meshgrid(range(a.shape[1]), range(a.shape[0]))
res = np.concatenate((x[:,:,None], y[:,:,None], a), axis = 2)
res = res.reshape(-1, a.shape[2]+2)

print(res)
```